# Ошибка при обновлении SSL сертефиката letsencrypt на centos 7.1

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, apache2.4, letsencrypt

Ошибка при обновлении SSL сертификата letsencrypt на centos 7.1, перепробовал много руководств, не работает, есть подозрения что что-то не так с конфигурацией apache, вот лог ошибки:

```
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...

Renewing an existing certificate

Performing the following challenges:

tls-sni-01 challenge for site.od.ua

tls-sni-01 challenge for site.agency

Waiting for verification...

Cleaning up challenges

Error while running apachectl graceful.

Job for httpd.service invalid.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: site.od.ua
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Timeout

   Domain: site.agency
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Timeout

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

Comment: 1. какой из десятков клиентов вы используете? 2. новый сертификат-то клиент получил?

Comment: Клиет использую этот https://github.com/certbot/certbot , по этом руководстве делал, https://www.8host.com/blog/sozdanie-sertifikata-lets-encrypt-dlya-apache-v-centos-7/, новый сертификат не генерится, после ошибок умирает apache, нужно вручную перезагружать

Comment: 1. попробуйте обновить клиент. 2. если не поможет: 2.1. https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/new 2.2. либо воспользуйтесь другим клиентом

Comment: а каким другим?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/